# Visualforce change ws to wss in some orgs (localhost)

Tags: visualforce, security, configuration

I have two sandboxes of different orgs.

I am trying to open visualforce with same code:

```
<apex:page >    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CONNECTION;
    window.onload = function () {
        CONNECTION = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1/chat');
        CONNECTION.onopen = function () {
            console.log('Hello!');
        };
    }
</script>
```

In first I got "Hello!" message, in other

> WebSocket connection to '**wss**://127.0.0.1/chat' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What can be a reason of this error? It looks like **ws** was replaced to **wss**. Which configurations should I check?